# Mozila Firefox Tool Tip Text

Tags: html, firefox, mozilla

to any component in html when i add tool tip text by alt="my tool tip text". it works in other browsers but not in fire fox. why. is there a way to enable it in firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alt != tooltip

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ#alttooltip) you can see why Firefox doesn't display the tooltip. Long story short, the alt attribute does not have anything to do with tooltips. It's just gotten into fashion over time, probably due to IE.

However, there are Javascript workarounds for displaying the tooltip anyway, but I suggest you take a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `title = "Your tooltip text"` ??

for example -

```
<a href="#" title= "Some text">Link</a> 

<div title= "Some text">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't display alt attributes as tooltips - it's a design decision.

You can use the title attribute instead (or as well).

Comment: It's not actually a "design decision", it's a question of standards compliance. "alt" attributes were never intended to be used as tooltips; "title" attributes were. Even Microsoft have finally accepted that they got it wrong, and have fixed this bug in IE 8 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the title attribute. For more information click [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/toolmsg.shtml). The title attribute works with all browsers. So it would be better if you go with that instead of alt.

Example:

```
<div id="blahblah" title='tooltip'>
```